# Electrical for Whole House Remodel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, remodeling

I'm looking at doing a room by room remodel. I know there would have to be a lot of electrical done which has been the biggest deterrent to date. I'm trying to get a grasp on how much, from what I can figure so far half the house or more would need to be redone. Currently have a 40 slot box with 35 used. Looking to get feed back on my proposed box layout below:

Bed 1             15A  (Incl./ Light)
Bed 2             15A  (Incl. Light)
Bed 3             15A  (Incl. Light)
Living            15A  (Incl. Light)
Dining            15A or 20A (Incl. Light)
Bath 1            20A  (Lighting Branch?)
Bath 2            20A  (Lighting Branch?)
Laundry           20A  (Lighting Branch?)
Utility           15A  (Incl/ Light)
Dishwasher        15A  (3 wire?, shared box)
Garbage disposle  15A  (3 wire?, shared box)
Fridge            20A  (15A meet code?)
Kitchen 1         20A  (split between top and bottom, 3 wire?)
Kitchen 2         20A  (split between top and bottom, 3 wire?)
Garage            20A  (Outside outlet also)
Lights            15A or 20A (Kitchen, garage, outside, Hall, Bathrooms?, Laundry?)
**16 slots          270A - 285A**

Bed 1 Heat        20A 1000w
Bed 2 Heat        20A 1000w
Bed 3 Heat        20A 1000w
Living Heat       20A 1200w
Dining Heat       20A 1200w
Kitchen Heat      20A 1200w
Bathroom Heat     20A 450w (switch to 120v or add Hall to branch?)
Hall heat         20A 450w (switch to 120v or add Bathroom to branch?)
A/C, Entry Heat   20A 14000 BTU/7A Heat combo
Dryer             30A HE
Water Heater      30A 4500w
Stove             50A 5000w
**24 Slots          290**

**Total  40 Slots, 580A**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many square feet is this house?  How many KW is your range?  Can you post photos of the nameplate on your air conditioner, as well as the labeling on the inside of the door of your existing panel? Who is your electric utility? Lastly, *why* are you heating your house with electric baseboards?!?!  (Your post doesn't provide nearly enough info to run a NEC load calculation on your house, never mind understand what your options are, other than getting rid of that electric baseboard heat...)

Comment: Following up on that: can you get us *photos* of the nameplates for the range and air-conditioner? Also, who do you have for an electric utility?

Comment: Can you get me your 99% design temperature, based on [this listing](https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/ACCA/c6b38bda-2e04-4f93-bd51-7a80525ad936/UploadedImages/Outdoor-Design-Conditions-1.pdf)?

Comment: Also, one last question: is replacing the meter socket/outside service equipment in the cards?

Comment: Instead of including a picture of a screen, it might be easier for people to read if you included a screen capture (you can do that with the computer whose screen we're looking at) and a link to the specs (include the specific model if there's more than one listed on the page).

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong here it's hard to know where to start and I don't have much time tonight. So here are my initial comments:

1. Separate your lighting circuits from your outlets, you don't want to be in the dark if a breaker trips.  On that sized house, with LED lighting you could easily run the lighting for entire house on 2 15 amp circuits (probably one, but I'm being cautious), if not LED lighting...why not? It's a game changer.
2. Your supply to the base board heaters is way over kill, a 1,000 watt heater at 240 will draw just over 4 amps. A 20 amp 240v circuit can supply 3,840 watts including derating for a continuous load (240 x 20 x .8 = 3,840 watts). Lots of your heaters could be combined into fewer circuits.
3. In some jurisdictions, depending upon which NEC code. Dining areas (dining room, kitchen nooks, etc.) need to be on a separate circuit from other living areas.   I think that's a stupid rule, but it is what it is.
4. Stay away from MWBCs (what you called 3-wire) for your kitchen and appliances.  They are a total PITA when it comes to GFCI/AFCI protection.  Given current wire pricing, you don't save anything by going with 12/3 vs 2 x 12/2.
5. Bathrooms require a dedicated 20 amp circuit, but that doesn't mean EACH bathroom has to have it's own circuit, that circuit can be shared by multiple bathrooms, that's up to you. I do prefer for each bathroom to have it's own circuit, but that's not required by code.

I'll think more about this and probably add to this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As to the Bathrooms, that was one of my biggest wonders. Each bathroom only has one outlet. I was under the impression that they would need to be separate. I had already rethought the 3 wire, like you say PITA. All lights are LED, More than half are already on one circuit. As to the heaters, I figured that already but wasn't sure why they were like that already, if they had to be sperate. The biggest ones are rated at 4.9A on the tag.

Comment: You might want to have more circuits for bathrooms. Hair dryers and space heaters (the plug in kind) take a lot of power and concurrent use could easily trip a 20 amp breaker. In my son's new build, he decided on a dedicated 20 amp circuit for each bathroom and the lighting on separate circuits (always a good practice anyway).  And my apologizes for my opening remark above, it was late and I was tired, but just wanted to give at least an initial resp.

Answer (score 1):

### First off: you don't need nearly that much electric heat

Your first order of business is pruning that heating system down, as it is *monstrously* oversized for your house, especially with the type of insulation details you're planning on (R32 walls, R60 attic) and air-sealing to match those.  Speaking of air-sealing, if you weren't already planning on "before and after" *blower door* tests, *do so*, as they'll give you the *hard truth* about your air-sealing practice, measured in *air changes per hour* at a given pressure, usually 50 Pascals.  The IRC's energy provisions (found in IRC N1102.4.1.2) generally limit you to a maximum of 3ach given your climate zone, while 1.5 is considered good, 1 excellent work, and 0.6 Passivhaus-level.

Once you have the envelope locked down tight, and a Heat Recovery Ventilator (HRV) fitted, then we can start talking about heat sources.  Your primary heat source, since you don't have gas, *will* be a proper heat pump; while the lack of ducts may sound like a barrier, it really isn't with today's ductless mini-split and multi-split systems.  Capacity-wise, you [*must*](https://www.acrightsize.com/files/elephant_in_the_room.pdf) run a proper Manual J, Eighth Edition load calculation, or have someone skilled in those run one for you, in order to get a working HVAC load for the house. However, for the purposes of electrical estimation on a house your size with your proposed envelope, we can assume that you'll need less than 24kbtu (two cooling tons) of capacity here.

This means that you can decommission a large chunk of that 7.5kW of electric space heat, as it's supplying over 24kbtu of heating capacity to the house *before* you add in whatever heat (strips or heatpump) your current through-the-wall HVAC unit provides.  Depending on your chosen heat pump's low ambient capabilities (top-of-the-line units, such as the Mitsubishi Hyper-Heat models, can [go down to -13°F](https://hvacdirect.com/hvac/pdf/MXZ3C24NAHZ2-U1-submittal.pdf)), you'll want a few kW of strategically placed electric heat still to make up the capacity shortfall heat pumps exhibit at low ambient temperatures, but that can be handled by a single 20A/240V circuit.

### With that out of the way, we can tackle the electrical issues

Now that we have the elephant in the room covered, we can move on to the actual electrical issues with your plan.  First and foremost, especially with LED lighting, separating lighting and receptacles onto their own circuits as you have more or less described makes sense.  However, I would have at least two lighting circuits in the house, so that a single breaker trip doesn't take down *all* the lights; one could divide them into "ambient lighting" and "task lighting", for instance.

We then move onto the kitchen, where we see trouble pop up, starting at the kitchen countertop receptacles.  Your plan to use split receptacles fed from a multi-wire branch circuit (MWBC) there is more or less a nonstarter due to a combination of factors:

- GFCI receptacles can't be split the way regular receptacles can, so you'd need two GFCIs at each outlet if you were using a two pole AFCI breaker with GFCI receptacles
- However, two-pole dual-function (AF + GF) breakers don't exist, either, so you'd need to use a two-pole 50A GFCI feeding a subpanel of two-pole 20A AFCIs instead, which introduces an extra box and a bunch of extra hassle if that GFCI ever trips
- Finally, the 2020 NEC tops it off by requiring GFCI protection for 240V kitchen countertop receptacles.  This means that if you wanted to use the MWBC to "sneak" 240V to the kitchen countertops, you'd need to use the box and subpanel setup instead.

As a result, you'll have to make a hard choice here, as you can either:

- provision conduit to the kitchen countertops, which isn't as costly as it sounds thanks to ENT ("smurf tube") being a thing, and gives you the power to change things down the road,
- accept the tradeoffs of having one GFCI breaker for *all the kitchen countertop receptacles* in order to have your MWBCs,
- use paired GFCI receptacles with 12/3 at the cost of not being able to get 240V to the countertop *or* use GFCI feed-thru protection
- or use 12/2/2 NM cable to provide split receptacles on handle-tied pairs of single-pole DFCIs at the cost of not being able to "sneak" 240V in.

With that taken care of, we can then move onto the other half of your kitchen troubles, namely that you don't have enough circuits provisioned for a properly functioning kitchen.  While having circuits for the dishwasher and disposal is a good start, the fact you only have two small appliance circuits for the kitchen counters is a bit of a penny-pinch.  Especially if you run ENT to the countertop boxes, going to a four-small-appliance-circuit kitchen doesn't add all that much cost, and provides you with much more flexibility with regards to juggling multiple small appliances at once.

Going back to the dishwasher and disposal circuits, these don't need to be on a MWBC either, as /2/2 NM cable, once again, *is* a thing that is made in this day and age.  (Ditching the MWBC for that also means you can locate the GFCI for the dishwasher in a convenient location.)  Finally, you *can* safely go to a 15A circuit for the fridge, as refrigerators don't need much power at all in this day and age.

We then exit the kitchen and enter the garage, which is the other place we should bump up the provisioning from the Code minimum.  You'll want a dedicated circuit for the garage's lighting and garage door openers, considering these are often tied together and the GDOs do take up a fairly significant chunk of the circuit's ampacity in any case, in addition to the dedicated garage receptacle circuit now required by the NEC.  Furthermore, providing a 50A/240V circuit for a future electric car charger (EVSE) or RV bay is a good idea at this point, as well.  In fact, one can get a "RV panel" box that has both 50A and 20A receptacles in it, as well as spare breaker spaces for the garage lighting/GDOs and extra garage receptacles, and *loop feed* lugs that can be used to send power off to a future garage subpanel; one of these on a 125A feeder, run using 1/0 Al SER, provides a fairly elegant, "all in one" solution to futureproofing a garage.

### As to box selection...

With all those issues covered, we can move onto selecting breaker boxes for your remodel.  As you can tell, your existing 40-space panel is pretty cramped as-is; while it might be able to accommodate your plans for now, given that we're taking out several of the existing heater circuits, there's no sense in not providing more room for expansion since we have the opportunity.

In that vein, we start at the meter since that's what has the most requirements attached, both by Xcel Energy and the current NEC.  In particular, the new 2020 NEC "emergency disconnect" requirements for single-family dwellings mean that a traditional setup with a standalone meter socket on the outside connected to a main breaker panel on the inside with SE (SEU, not to be confused with USE) cable will no longer fly.  As a result, you'll want to upgrade to a *meter main* when you redo the outside box, but this requires you to change the feed from outside to inside to a 4-wire *feeder* with separate neutral and grounding wires, usually run using SER cable.  Furthermore, that upgrade practically requires you to convert your panel to a *main lug* panel from a *main breaker* type, which is somewhat limiting as to your choices for new panels.

As far as meter-mains go, I'd use a Siemens MC0816B1200JLT, Eaton MBX816B200BTS or CMBX1212B200BTS, Square-D QC816F200SL or RC816F200SL, or Milbank U6281-XL-200-5T9; all of these meet the requirements Xcel imposes on metering hardware and provide a few spare breaker spaces in addition to a set of *feed-through lugs* coming directly off the busses.  From there, I'd run 250kcmil Al SER to a 54-space or 60-space, 200A or 225A, convertible panel, fitted with grounding bars.  This way, you can order it as a main panel initially and wire it with neutrals and grounds separated but bonded, so that when the meter-main gets installed, you can run the SER cable from the meter-main to the panel, convert the panel to main lug, and pull the bonding screw to turn into a subpanel off the meter-main.

While you're at it, you'll want to fit a Type 2 SPD and matching breaker at the meter-main; this is also a 2020 NEC requirement, and provides a convenient home for the surge suppression right where power comes into the house.  If you're looking for panel part numbers for the inside panel, you're looking at a CHP60E225X9 or BRP60E200 with a GBKP2120 ground bar and CSR2200 main breaker fitted if you are an Eaton fan, a PN5482B1225C or SN5482B1200 if you prefer Siemens for this, or a Square-D QO154M200P(C) or QO160M200PC fitted with a PK23GTAL or PK27GTAL grounding bar.  (You could get the QO panels in main lug and fit a QOM2200VH main breaker to them, but it's cheaper to get the main breaker version and swap it to main lugs instead.)

### TORQUE ALL LUGS TO SPEC

Finally, you'll want to use an inch-pound torque wrench or torque screwdriver (depending on the torque needed) to torque all breaker and panel lugs down to their stated connection torques.  This is a new requirement in the 2017 NEC, and is a good idea even if your AHJ doesn't enforce it, lest your electrical system go off and [lose you the race!](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2010/07/16/the-difference-between-success-and-failure-how-a-torque-wrench-improves-system-reliability/)

Comment: @Joe -- I'd explain your construction phasing to the inspector ahead of time; what you currently have will still work for an existing house, but this is a major enough remodel that  bringing the service entrance up to current Code will likely be required

Comment: @Joe -- you have some funky microclimate going on where you live if you're claiming temp drops *that* deep with a 99% temp of -11degF.  You'll still be able to get good mileage out of a heatpump with a few kW of supplemental heat, though, although I wouldn't go out and buy new heaters until I had Manual J and S calcs performed

Comment: Got 2 questions, 1) if a light that is powered with the room outlets on 12 ga, can the connection between 2 three way switches be 14 ga and the circuit still able to use a 20A breaker? 2) in an inaccessible attic can wires be run diagonal across the top of the joist is a somewhat star pattern, with or without raceways for wire efficiency?

Comment: @joe -- no and yes

Comment: @Joe -- you'll likely need to use *running boards* (1x is fine) to run the cables in your attic atop if you're going diagonal with them, though

Comment: Working on plans to migrate all lights to a singe circuit, 2A for the whole house. Can wire be run at any height horizontally in walls. Also what's the minimum hole size for 1 cable?

Comment: @Joe -- yes, although I'd split the lights into two circuits myself for serviceability reasons, and 14-10AWG NM-B should fit in a 1/2" hole, although 12/2 and 10/2 will be quite a tight fit through it, so you might want to bump up to a 5/8" for those

Comment: Oh lord, I've been bouncing around on the light branch and finally settled on one dedicated one now I don't know again. If I brought in an electrician to upgrade my box and breakers to get that part out of the way first, does that need to be inspected?

Comment: @Joe -- it depends on your AHJ whether they'll do a rough inspection of the breakers/panel only, or want to defer it to when you have the wiring roughed in as well.

Comment: Got a new box ordered, the 42 slot version of your suggestion. An extra $10 for the Value pack with 5 AFCI breakers, nice. Still going to be full but will be enough. The inspector told me I could use a standard breaker on the water heater as long as the is a safety switch in the room. Is that still required with an AFCI breaker. Can't locate a decent $30 switch, might as well do a breaker if that will cut it. Building supplies are getting weird, paid $10 for 2 - 1 x 3 x8's.

Comment: @Joe -- you don't need an AFCI for a water heater, for one (unless it's some direct vent gas thingy that requires 120V *and* is mounted in something that's a living space) -- what the inspector was referring to with the safety switch was not needing a *lockoff* on the breaker, although lockoff devices for modern panels are pretty cheap/easy to find if you know what you're looking for.  Also, if you're burning 42 spaces that readily, I'd get a second 42 space panel and put it in (not necessarily *now*, but certainly when the new meter-main goes in)

Comment: @Joe -- which make/line of panel did you pick in the end?

Comment: Oh, staying with Square D QO, even with the wiring here, never had a single breaker trip. The box was a good deal from what I can tell. $260 shipped with cover, 5 AFCI breakers for the QO line.

Comment: @Joe -- ah, yeah, QO's definitely not a *bad* choice in 99% of circumstances (their 2-pole AFCIs don't play nice with 208V power, but other than that, they are good).  You'll want a QO1PL or QO2PAF lockoff (the former can also be used to lock a breaker ON, that's the only real difference) for your water heater breaker, by the way

Comment: I'm under the impression the  inspector meant one of these of the water heater, He said in didn't need anything at all if within 50 ft and line of sight of the box:   https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/circuit-protection-distribution/safety-switches-disconnects/ge-30-amp-240v-non-fused-safety-switch/tgn3321cp/p-1444431225223-c-6435.htm?tid=1509334512377990205&ipos=39

Comment: @Joe -- yeah, you could use one of those visible from the water heater instead of the lockoff, but the lockoff option's cheaper and somewhat easier to install.

Comment: Is that (done either way) for the sole purpose of servicing. I guess the inspector made it sound like he wants something that can be used as an "emergency disconnect". Think I'm going to order a box linked to make his specific guy happy, I don't mind having it right there either. Also needed a box anyways to go from wall to water heater. I have back ordered 8/3 cable a week over due already, might take a while to arrive.

Comment: @Joe -- the switch or lockoff is for servicing, yes, and why 8/3 for the water heater run, since a typical tank is on a 30A circuit and doesn't need a neutral?

Comment: That's for the stove, got 10/2 for the water heater. Currently it's on 12/2 with a 30A breaker with a draw of 19A. Looking to get that remedied ASAP.

Comment: Am correct in assuming a 15A tandem breaker would work for my 240v heaters to get them to a single slot? after checking into your suggested meter boxes, I'm wondering if I should go with a homeline series box that supports tandem breakers. That would give me plenty of extra space inside. Also found a homeline meter box that comes with the SPD. The $100+ savings on the inside box and cheaper breakers would pay for the meter box.  Thanks for all your assistance, I don't have the rep for chat, was going to see if you had a PayPal I could send a tip to :).

Comment: @Joe -- I take it you've already consolidated the heat circuits as far as they'll go?

Comment: I didn't... I'd like to keep them separate, partly for the winter service-abliity. Partly to make it simpler for going room by room. Mostly for efficiency even if it seems negligible. Where the wires are is much warmer than room temperature with the cove heaters and i'd like lowest possible resistance. Edit: I know my cove heaters are stupid, by they feel like direct sun in the winter, I really like them.

Comment: @Joe -- I'd temporarily consolidate a couple of heaters onto the same circuit for now then (plain QO breakers 15-30A accept 2 14-10AWG Cu under their lugs, so it's really easy to do)

Comment: Sill working on planing my 2 circuit lighting setup. I ended up being able to cancel the box I ordered and got the 42/84 Homeline with 225 main breaker included. Do outdoor lights need to be gfci? Also is it common or acceptable to "T" off of a another switch box rather than everyone point to point daisy chained or would that be frowned upon or considered cheap?

Comment: @Joe -- GFCI only applies to outdoor receptacles, and topology-wise, as long as you don't create loops or overstuff a box, you're pretty much free to do whatever you wish.  Also, why the switch from QO to HOM?

Comment: Cheaper (in quality too I know), I wasn't originally planning on get a box and all breakers at the same time. Rated to use tandem breakers. Mostly I got the one I did because it came with the 225 main. If you can find one, they are not cheap. More than with the box in fact. Also the HOM SPD is affordable, and will fit it the slots on the inside or outside box as that is planed to be a HOM one as that is what is in my price that has a 225 rated bus.

Comment: Can 120v and 240v be ran in the same stud hole?

Comment: @Joe -- there is nothing against that in the NEC

Comment: Still working on this, got a nice lighting I setup using these to control 4 can lights, hopefully the inspector won't say anything about having that many sitches for the same lights. Should can lights be in series or parallel?                   https://www.menards.com/main/storeitem.html?iid=1478848691539 https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/light-switches-dimmers-outlets/dimmer-controls/legrand-reg-wide-slide-led-decorator-dimmer/wscl450tcccv4/p-1452209499248-c-6321.htm?tid=-2193849812057514139&ipos=26

Comment: @Joe -- you can wire a string of can lights off the same switched feed, but loads need to be electrically in parallel to work properly

Comment: Is it necessary in current code to run 2 cables in to a light switch box or is it still OK to run one from the fixture and tape the neutral?

Comment: Also if that is acceptable, is it OK in that situation to use 3 wire between the fixture and switch box to continue the circuit from the switch box.

Comment: And than if that is OK, is it ok to repeat that (2 wire, 3 wire, 2 wire, 3 wire, fixture, switch, fixture, switch) multiple time on the same circuit.

Comment: @Joe -- you can still run a switch loop down to the fixture, but it needs to have a "dead end" neutral wire in it (so, /3 instead of /2 and so on).

Comment: So does that neutral (in the switch box) have to be "Dead" or can it be used to continue the circuit by pig-tailing the hot in the switch box? Also is the need to use 3 wire because a taped neutral is not allowed? Currently I have a lot of hot neutrals (many 3/4 ways) that I had to go around, find and tape 40 years after the install.

Comment: @Joe -- there is nothing stopping you from continuing the circuit using the always-hot and neutral that you now have at the switch box -- and the issue is that neutral is needed at switch complexes now, what you're seeing in the "old style" loops isn't a "taped neutral" but a "white-as-hot"

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm working on my terminology. So does the same apply to 3-way switches? For instance if I have a 3-way switch with nothing else in the box, would that then require a 4 wire conductor?

Comment: @Joe -- 3-way switches introduce a twist because you only need neutral at one switch location within a 3-way complex.  In practice, this means you can run /3 from the light to the first switch, then have /3 continuing on to any number of additional switches as long as those additional switch locations don't need neutral

Comment: Hello again, still at it. I've hopped full on the mini spit heat pump train. should have had this on my radar the last time I replaced the wall A/C. I'm sure I could probably do everything with 2 3-zone's. Question is, is there a practical way to have the wall units on inside walls? With the one in question I'm thinking the only way to put it where I want would be to drop the lines trough the ceiling.

Comment: @Joe -- AFAIK, you're just limited by the manufacturer specs on lineset length and rise (since there's oil flowing in the refrigerant loop -- those are limits for any A/C or heat-pump, not just minisplits, btw)

Comment: I haven't even got that far, I guess from what I can tell from my research is they require a 3.5 inch hole which I'm unwilling to do on inside walls because I can only go in from the top plate (especially for this one as I'd like it on the center, longways, load bearing wall). Also happens where I want the outside wall ones they would have to go through headers. Any issues there (these are LARGE old school headers, largest 14"x10'.

Comment: @Joe -- what diameter is the vapor line for the unit you're looking at? 3.5" sounds rather...excessive for refrigerant...

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Pioneer-Multi-36-000-BTU-3-Ton-22-SEER-Triple-3-Zone-Wall-Mount-Air-Conditioner-Heat-Pump-230-Volt-16-ft-WYS030GMHI22M3/314511887    install instructions say 2.5 or 3.5 in depending on model. All the install videos I found do a 3.5 in.

Comment: @Joe -- that's because you're using a system that's using a preinsulated lineset -- not having to stuff a bunch of foam thru a top plate hole will help tremendously on this front.

Comment: I pulled the trigger on a single triple zone and 3 9,000 btu wall units, the pioneer linked from another specialized vendor with 33ft install kits. Going to keep 4 1000w baseboard heaters one in each bedroom and one in the dining room. After getting into the drainage stuff I realized there is only one place that makes sense to install is in a "T" at the core of the house which is the water utilities closet.  One in kitchen, one bed off kitchen, one in living room, dining room is between kitchen and living, one down the hall to 2 beds.

Comment: Don't nee to run anything laterally in the walls, will go through the ceiling in the utility closet. Have drains in there. No in wall wiring needed, will go out the soffit. That will be the next thing needing advice on, what type of conduit for that and where in the attic/soffit space the conduit needs to start?

Comment: https://www.pioneerminisplit.com/collections/multi-split-systems/type_triple-zones

Comment: @Joe -- I'd use a PVC or EMT conduit from the outside disconnect to where it enters the house, then use a box to transition to your indoor wiring method of choice.  You'll need to use a LL or LR body (pick whichever one has the cover facing out) to transition from the disconnect to the conduit though, it sounds like